# when I am running my javafx program I am getting invocationtargetexception

Tags: exception, javafx, invocationtargetexception

When I am trying to run my javafx application, I am getting  exceptions as follows:

Exception in Application start method

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:642)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at duraapp.Duraapp.start(Duraapp.java:61)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
... 1 more
```

Comment: What is at (Duraapp.java:61)?

Comment: Put your code up homie.